# Regular expressions to capture text around <div> tags?

Tags: regex

I have a bunch of products that i need the title and description text so i can put them into a query that looks something like this:
INSERT INTO uc_products (title, description) values
('Lafayette RK-820 4 track stereo tape deck','Operation and service manual, includes parts list &amp; schematic'),

The info is currently collected in some div tags:

```
<div class="radio-product-wrap">
    <div class="radio-product-image">

    </div>
    <div class="radio-product-title">
        <p>Lafayette RK-820 4 track stereo tape deck</p>
    </div>
    <div class="radio-product-desript">
        <p>Operation and service manual, includes parts list &amp;amp; schematic</p>
    </div>
    <div class="radio-cart-66-wrap">
        [add_to_cart item="L-1"]
    </div>
</div>
```

How would i write a regular expression to get the info?

Comment: **STATUARY WARNING:** Using regular expressions for this type of html parsing is dangerous. Consider using a lite HTML Parser instead.

Comment: I second what @anubhava says, you'll also find it easier in the long run for this kind of thing. If you mention which language you're using then you might get some recommendations for parsers to use. Nice username by the way, top dj.

Comment: This warning is not expressly true for *all* cases. It is *VERY* true if one wishes to parse arbitrary HTML documents. However and as I note in my response, extracting predictable elements from *well-defined* HTML is an excellent usecase for regular expressions and they perform exceptionally well doing so.

Answer (score 3):

In which target language? Or do you simply require the regular expression itself?

Note that regular expressions are only useful when extracting well-defined parts of HTML documents and cannot be used to generally *parse* HTML.

If all you need is a regex, you could use:

```
<div\ class="radio-product-title">    # literal div tag with class

[^<]*                                 # any chars that are not '<'

<p>                                   # literal '<p>' tag

\s*                                   # optional leading spaces

([^<]+?)                              # one or more chars that are not '<', 
                                      #   captured in to group #1
                                      # (non-greedy)

\s*                                   # optional trailing spaces

<\/p>                                 # literal '</p>' tag

[^<]*                                 # any chars that are not '<'

<\/div>                               # literal '</div>' end tag

[^<]*                                 # any chars that are not '<'

<div\ class="radio-product-desript">  # literal div tag with class

[^<]*                                 # any chars that are not '<'

<p>                                   # literal '<p>' tag

\s*                                   # optional leading spaces

([^<]+?)                              # one or more chars that are not '<', 
                                      #   captured in to group #2
                                      # (non-greedy)

\s*                                   # optional trailing spaces

<\/p>                                 # literal '</p>' tag
```

Same thing without comments:

```
<div\ class="radio-product-title">[^<]*<p>\s*([^<]+?)\s*<\/p>[^<]*<\/div>[^<]*<div\ class="radio-product-desript">[^<]*<p>\s*([^<]+?)\s*<\/p>
```

This regex assumes there are no '<' chars between `<p>` and `</p>` tags.  IF this is not the case, it will need to be revised.

Depending on your target language, you may need to tell your regex engine to treat the source string as 'single line' during processing.

On completion, match[1] will contain the title and match[2] the description.

---

EDIT in response to the warning comment...

While it is true that you cannot use regular expressions to reliably parse *arbitrary HTML documents*, they are an excellent tool for extracting elements from such documents IFF:

1. The format is the same across all documents.
2. The targeted elements are well-defined and easily recognizable.

To warn people away from using regular expressions when extracting data *under these conditions* is to succumb to dogma without understanding.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<div class="radio-product-title">.*?<p>(?<Title>.*?)</p>.*?</div>.*?<div class="radio-product-desript">.*?<p>(?<Description>.*?)</p>.*?</div>
```

You need to capture two named groups `Title` and `Description` from the match.